# How to read/write to raw device with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have to read and write data (up to 512 bytes) to/from raw disks (first sector on disk, and first sector on partitions).

I'd like to use PowerShell for that, but fail to find any reference to access to raw disks and raw partitions.

Whats is/are the way/s to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in PowerShell most of the things you can do in .NET (with C# or another language). You will find in [CCS LABS C#: Low Level Disk Access](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CCS-LABS-C-Low-Level-Disk-91676ca9) the way to do it in C#, but really I'am not sure it's a good idea to do that using a scripting language.